# Prestashop 1.7 $this->translator->trans in customerformatter override

Tags: overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm overriding the getFormat () function in the customerformatter class.
Here $this-> translator-> trans doesn't work.

So what is the best way to recall the translation of the type fields

```
$format['company'] = (new FormField)
->setName('company')
->setType('text')
->setLabel($this->translator->trans(
'Company', [], 'Shop.Forms.Labels'
));
```

If I overwrite the whole customerformatter class, obviously everything works.
Thank you

Comment: Could you post whole of your override file?

Comment: For example:

class CustomerFormatter extends CustomerFormatterCore { 
 public function getFormat()
    {
        if (Configuration::get('PS_B2B_ENABLE')) {
   If (Context::getContext()->cookie->mygroup) {
     $format['company'] = (new FormField)
     .....
.... 
->setLabel($this->translator->trans(
      'Company', [], 'Shop.Forms.Labels'
     ))    
->setRequired(true);
... and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error for `translator` and `language` because in main core class `CustomerFormatterCore`; properties like `translator` and `language` are having `private` visibility so it can't be accesses in child class which is override class `CustomerFormatter` in our case.

We need to declare these properties as `private` again and need to inject it in `__construct()` method.

Follow below steps to achieve what you want.

1) Create file `CustomerFormatter.php` in `override\classes\form` folder and add below code in it.

```
<?php
/**
 * @Override CustomerFormatter
 */

use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class CustomerFormatter extends CustomerFormatterCore
{
    private $translator;
    private $language;

    public function __construct(
        TranslatorInterface $translator,
        Language $language
    ) {
        parent::__construct($translator, $language);
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->language = $language;
    }

    public function getFormat()
    {
        $format = parent::getFormat();

        if (Configuration::get('PS_B2B_ENABLE')) {
            $format['company'] = (new FormField)
                ->setName('company')
                ->setType('text')
                ->setLabel($this->translator->trans(
                    'Company', [], 'Shop.Forms.Labels'
                ));
        }
        // add formatter here as per your need            

        return $format;
    }
}
```

2) Delete `class_index.php` file from `var\cache\prod` and `var\cache\dev` folder.

3) Check your shop.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Is it just me or is it bad design to have put these fields private instead of protected ?

Comment: Design is perfectly fine; main core file having this variables as private so we have to inject this in __construct() and define them as private